# Getting "Please rebuild this data combination" on a computer but not on another one

Tags: excel, parameters, powerquery, firewall

This is my first try at using the Power Query... I've build a "dynamic" query in which I can change the retrieved fields as well as the filtering fields and values to be used by the query.

It's working perfectly on my computer but as soon as I try to execute it on another computer, I get the "Please rebuild this data combination" error.  I saw some post saying I'll have to kind of split my query but I have not been able to figure it out.

Here is what my 2 tables look like:
[Condition and fields selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faCqd.png)

and here is my Query with the error:
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Limbf.png)

This might not be very elegant, but it allow me, thru a VBA script, to generate the list of fields to be retrieved and to generate the condition to be used by the SQL.

Any idea why it's not working on the other computers or how to improved the solution I'm using?

Thank you!

**Notes:**
Hi,  all my Privacy Level are already set to 'None'.
I've tried to parametrize my code but I can't figure how.  The Where condition is dynamic: it could be *Where Number = "1234"*  but in other condition, the where might be like: *'Where Assignee = "xyz"'*.

Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
   let
    Source = Sql.Database("xxxx", "yyyy", [Query=
      "Select network, testid
        from CM3T1M1 "
       & paramConditions[Conditions]{0} &
      " "])
   in
    Source
```

Comment: Do all computers have the same version of programs? All up to date?

Comment: "It's working perfectly on my computer but as soon as I try to execute it on another computer," Their `privacy query settings` probably haven't been set. --- Otherwise we'd need errors, the query, maybe a screenshot.

Comment: Yes they are both running on the latest version of Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

## rebuild query, `Formula.Firewall`

That's a feature to prevent prevent accidentally leaking data. [You can change the privacy level to ignore it](https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2019/03/12/data-privacy-and-the-formula-firewall/)

See also: [docs.microsoft/dataprivacyfirewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dataprivacyfirewall)

Is the dynamic query inserting those cells into the SQL query ? `Report Parameters` are nice for letting the user change variables without having to re-edit the query.

## Parameterized native SQL queries

from: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/12/11/passing-parameters-to-sql-queries-with-value-nativequery-in-power-query-and-power-bi/

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("localhost", "Adventure Works DW"),
    Test = Value.NativeQuery(
        Source,
        "SELECT * FROM DimDate 
        WHERE EnglishMonthName=@MonthName AND
            EnglishDayNameOfWeek=@DayName",
        [
            MonthName = "March",
            DayName = "Tuesday"
        ]
    )
in
    Test
```

## Dynamic Power Query version of SQL Query

### To dynamically generate this SQL Query

```sql
select NUMBER, REQUESTED_BY from SourceTable
where NUMBER = 404115
```

- `Table.SelectRows` is your `Where`.
- `SelectColumns` is your `select`

```
let
    Source = ...,
    filterByNum = 404115,
    columnNames = {"NUMBER", "REQUESTED_BY"},

    removedColumns = Table.SelectColumns(
        Source, columnNames, MissingField.Error
    ),
    // I used 'MissingField.Error' so you know right away
    // if there's a typo or bug

    // assuming you are comparing Source[NUMBER]
    filteredTable = Table.SelectRows(
        Source, each [NUMBER] = filterByNum
    )  
in 

    filteredTable
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help.  Please look at the Note I've added to my problem.

Comment: That's in my second section. If you want the variable `query`, then the SQL needs to have `@Query`. It matches the names in the record you pass.